# JAXB - Change the structure child node

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have the structure generatade in jaxb:

`<Crm>
     <codigo>000</codigo>
     <uf>GO</uf>
     <crm>7784CRM</crm>
     <Especialidade>
        <codigo>13</codigo>
        <nome>CIRURGIA</nome>
     </Especialidade>
     <Especialidade>
        <codigo>14</codigo>
        <nome>CIRURGIA GERAL</nome>
    </Especialidade>
</Crm>`

I need this structure

`<Crm>
     <codigo>0000</codigo>
     <uf>GO</uf>
     <crm>0000CRM</crm>
     <Especialidade>
        <codigo>13</codigo>
        <nome>CIRURGIA PLASTICA</nome>
        <codigo>14</codigo>
        <nome>CIRURGIA GERAL</nome>
    </Especialidade>
</Crm>`

The CrmDTO class:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class CrmDTO extends ParentDTO {

@XmlElement(name="codigo")
private Long CODIGO;

@XmlElement(name="uf")
private String UF;

@XmlElement(name="crm")
private String CRM;

@XmlElement(name = "Especialidade")
private List<EspecialidadeDTO> especialidades;
```

The EspecialidadeDTO class:

```
@XmlType(propOrder= {"CODIGO", "NOME"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class EspecialidadeDTO extends ParentDTO {

@XmlElement(name="codigo")
private Long CODIGO;

@XmlElement(name="nome")
private String NOME;
```

I've tried several ways and can not help the way I want.
Put some Annotations I found some tutorials but failed

Comment: I don't see `nome` in your class.

Comment: inserted new code in question

Comment: The XML format you currently have is much easier to process (by any XML tool I can think of) as a collection and is very tolerant to ordering and missing elements.  Do you have a hard requirement to deliver the format you are looking for?

Comment: Particularly I also think a lot easier. But I will send the XML to a web service, and the need to be in xml format that I quoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need to represent the `name` and `codigo` elements to one `List` property annotated with `@XmlElements` to get the behaviour you are looking for:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Crm")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class CrmDTO extends ParentDTO {

    @XmlElement(name = "codigo")
    private Long CODIGO;

    @XmlElement(name = "uf")
    private String UF;

    @XmlElement(name = "crm")
    private String CRM;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="Especialidade")
    @XmlElements({
      @XmlElement(name="codigo", type=Long.class),
      @XmlElement(name="name", type=String.class)
    })
    private List<Object> especialidades;

}
```

Comment: returned the error: EspecialidadeDTO class and any of its superclass is known to this context

Comment: @adelmo00 - Instead of using `List<EspecialidadeDTO>` you are going to need to have a list of `Object` where the contents are either a `String` or `Long`.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve the result without changing the object type of the List?

Comment: I changed and returned other error: class [Ljava.lang.Object class and any of its superclass is known to this context